# View permission item of dynamic module auto change "Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicModules.Model.DynamicContent" to [object%20Object]

Tags: c#, api, error-handling, sitefinity

[issue img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEFNN.png)

Like you see above : 500 Type "[object Object]" cannot be resolved.
if i change [object Object] with Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicModules.Model.DynamicContent then it works but i can not do that because this api call inside Sitefinity.
Sorry cause i do not enough 10 poin to add image!!

Version 11.1.6825.0
Step to reproduce :

- login to backend page
- Go to => Content / "Dynamic module Name"/ Action/ Permission

Actually it only happen with some Dynamic module, not all of them so i am also not sure what is happening.

Comment: sitefinity version and steps to reproduce?

Comment: I changed it. thanks

Comment: If it happens to only some of the modules, I would take a wild guess and say that maybe one of the fields of that module has a name that is a reserved word, e.g. Property or something like that. I would check all field names and see if any of them look suspicious.

Comment: I would agree with @VeselinVasilev, and I would probably start with changing the name of `object Object` to `object SomeOtherName`, since `object` is a reserved word almost everywhere.

Comment: Title (Short text) ,
InternalLevelPosition (Choices),
ManagementLevel (Choices),
FullName (Short text),
Order (Number),
ManagementPic Related media (images, videos, files),
This is all field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @Veselin Vasilev that correct after i remove FullName field it is fine.
Solution : Remove the field FullName.